# While sculpting, whenever I use the mirroring tool it has a tendency to not be symmetrical. And i can't find a damn solution for it :(

Tags: sculpting, mirror

I'm fairly new to blender and i have recently been following a sculpting tutorial. I have this problem where whenever I use the mirroring tool the mirror dots are not symmetrical to each other [image: An example] and it drives me crazy. I know its something about the origin point or the scale, rotation, location but I've checked all those and everything seems to be normal.

Comment: Yes, the mirror tool uses the object's origin for the mirror. It's indicated by a little orange dot. Have you tried to reset the object's origin into the center with the menu entry *Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*?

Comment: Yes. I have multiple times, that's why it's bothering me so much.

Comment: (Hm, for some reason Blender does not show the origin in *Sculpt* mode even it's enabled in the overlay ...?) According to the *Location* of the N-panel in your screenshot, you have applied the *Location*. This means the origin should be at the world origin (0,0,0). And the model must be centered on the X-axis to have the mirror work correctly. Can you check this in *Object* mode?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyFVA.jpg

Comment: It says the same in object mode, everything is on the (0,0,0). The model should be perfectly centered including the origin. Despite all that the mirroring is still asymmetrical. Could it be that the model itself is not symmetrical?